# Force Nestjs Mongoose to return a class instance instead of a js object

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

The problem is quite simple :

- I have a simple class named *User*
- I make a findOne with the *userModel* to retrieve my *User* based on his email
- **The problem** is that i get a js object (i.e. Object { ... }) and not a instance of my User (i.e. User {...})

Is there a way to do that ?
Is there a way to make TypeScript crash if the returned object is not a *User* ?
I thought that the *HydratedDocument* was used for that purpose but obviously not ...
What is it for in this case ?

If you have any suggestion on my code it will be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance !

Definition of my User :

```
export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>;

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({ required: true, type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId })
  public _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: String })
  public firstname: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: String })
  public lastname: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: String })
  public email: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: String })
  public password: string;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Organization',
    required: true,
  })
  public organization: Organization;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

My service definition :

```
@Injectable()
export class MongodbUserDataSource implements UserDataSource {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

  /**
   * Get the user by its email
   * @param {string} email - The user email
   * @returns {User} The user corresponding to the email
   */
  async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.userModel
      .findOne({ email: email })
      .populate('organization')
      .lean()
      .exec();
  }
}
```

Here is my module definition :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Organization.name, schema: OrganizationSchema },
    ]),
    PassportModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    LocalStrategy,
    AuthService,
    LoginUseCase,
    UseCases,
    UserRepository,
    {
      useClass: MongodbUserDataSource,
      provide: UserDataSource,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```